# setState method to change this.state.prop not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

making a simple react app but my `getDates` function is not working like I want it to. I am successfully able to set the value of `tdayDate`, and then I want to change the value of `this.state.todayDate` to `tdayDate` but I cannot do so. I tried changing the value of `this.state.todayDate` to any random string using the `setState` method but that does not work either so I think the error is on the `this.setState` line. I tried using both the traditional function and the arrow function as well. Any idea what is wrong? I tried googling and reading react documentation but I can't find what is wrong. Thank you.

order-form.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './order-form.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

export default class OrderForm extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            nameId : '',
            phoneNu : '',
            emailId : '',
            pizzaSz : '',
            topping : '',
            delivTime : '',
            instru : '-',
            isModalOpen : false,
            todayDate : '',
            endDate: ''
        }

        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.getDates = this.getDates.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDates();
        axios
        .post('http://httpbin.org/post', this.state)
        .then(response => {console.log("Response: " + response)})
        .catch(error => {console.log("Error: " + error)})
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    }

    submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    openModal(e){
        this.setState({ isModalOpen : true });
    }

    closeModal(e){
        if (this.state.isModalOpen) {
            this.setState({ isModalOpen : false })
        }
    }

    getDates(e){
        var tdayDate = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + new Date().getMonth() + "-" + new Date().getDate() + "T" +  new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();

        if (tdayDate[6]==="-"){
            tdayDate = tdayDate.substring(0, 5) + "0" + tdayDate.substring(5, tdayDate.length);
        };
        
        if (tdayDate[9]==="T"){
            tdayDate = tdayDate.substring(0, 8) + "0" + tdayDate.substring(8, tdayDate.length);
        };

        if (tdayDate[8]==="-"){
            tdayDate = tdayDate.substring(0, 7) + "0" + tdayDate.substring(7, tdayDate.length);
        };

        if (tdayDate[12]===":"){
            tdayDate = tdayDate.substring(0, 11) + "0" + tdayDate.substring(11, tdayDate.length);
        };

        if (tdayDate.length === 15){
            tdayDate = tdayDate.substring(0, 14) + "0" + tdayDate.substring(14, tdayDate.length);
        };
        
        this.setState({ todayDate : tdayDate });
        console.log(this.state.todayDate);
    }

    render() {
        const{ nameId, phoneNu, emailId, pizzaSz, topping, delivTime, instru, 
            isModalOpen, todayDate, endDate } = this.state;
        return(
        <div className="" onClick={this.closeModal}>
            <h1 className="mt-5 mb-4 text-center">Order A Pizza!</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <div className="contact-details px-3">
                    Customer name: <input type="text" name="nameId"
                    value={nameId} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                    Telephone: <input type="number" name="phoneNu"
                    value={phoneNu} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                    E-mail address: <input type="email" name="emailId"
                    value={emailId} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>
                </div>

                <div className="mt-4 px-3 py-2 pizza-details">
                    <p className="label font-weight-bold">Pizza Size<br/></p>
                    <input type="radio" id="sm" name="pizzaSz" value="sm" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="sm">Small (10")</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="md" name="pizzaSz" value="md" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="md">Medium (13")</label><br/>
                    <input type="radio" id="lg" name="pizzaSz" value="lg" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="lg">Large (15")</label><br/>
                </div>
                
                <div className="px-3 py-2 pizza-details">
                    <p className="label font-weight-bold">Pizza Topping </p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="bacon" name="topping" value="bacon" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="bacon"> Bacon</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="excheese" name="topping" value="excheese" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="excheese"> Extra Cheese</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="onion" name="topping" value="onion" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="onion"> Onion</label><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="mushrm" name="topping" value="mushrm" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                    <label for="mushrm">Mushroom</label><br/>
                </div>
                
                <div className="px-3 delivery-details">
                    Preferred Delivery Time: <input type="datetime-local" name="delivTime" name="delivTime" value={delivTime} 
                    onChange={this.changeHandler} min={this.tdayDate} max="2021-07-28T00:00"/><br/>
        
                    Delivery Intructions: <input type="text" name="instru" id="instru"
                    value={instru} onChange={this.changeHandler}/><br/>                    
                </div>
                <div className="text-center mb-6">
                <button className="btn btn-success mt-3 mb-5" type="submit" 
                    onClick={this.openModal}
                    >Submit Order</button>
                </div>
                
            </form>

            <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen}>
                <div  className="modal-custom px-5 pt-3 pb-5" onClick={this.openModal}>
                    <h2 className="text-center text-success font-weight-bold">ORDER SUCCESS</h2><br/>

                    <p>Name: {this.state.nameId}</p>
                    <p>Phone number: {this.state.phoneNu}</p>
                    <p>Email ID: {this.state.emailId}</p><br/>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Size</th>
                            <th scope="col">Toppings</th>
                            <th scope="col">Delivery Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">Instructions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td>{this.state.pizzaSz}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.topping}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.delivTime}</td>
                            <td>{this.state.instru}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    *please refresh the page to make another order
                    <div className="text-center mt-2">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary mr-2">Print Receipt</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import OrderForm from './components/forms/order/order-form';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8 mx-auto content px-5">
          <OrderForm/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you could provide a working example with codePen that would be perfect.

Comment: It seems like you `console.log` right after setting state. But note that, [React `setState` is asynchronous](https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/), and therefore the updated value may (and usually) not be available right after you just set state

Comment: By the way, in order to get a valid console log you should use setState's callback. For example:

`this.setState({ todayDate : tdayDate },()=> console.log(this.state.todayDate))`